# Solve the following equation $ \frac{1}{2^x} + \frac{1}{4^x} + \frac{1}{6^x} + \frac{1}{8^x} = 1 $ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve the following equation?

> $$ 
> \dfrac{1}{2^x} + 
> \dfrac{1}{4^x} + 
> \dfrac{1}{6^x} + 
> \dfrac{1}{8^x} = 
> 1 
> $$

Comment: This, at least to me, seems pretty hard. Are you sure that this is the correct equation you need to solve?

Comment: Do you literally mean "*solve*", or maybe "*determine if/how many real roots exist*"?

Comment: To find this unique real solution, one can solve it numerically using the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: @Tim Ong ; 
Let's define 
$ 
f(x) =
\dfrac{1}{2^x} + 
\dfrac{1}{4^x} + 
\dfrac{1}{6^x} + 
\dfrac{1}{8^x} 
$ .  
Notice that $f(2) < 1 < f(1)$ ; so the equation has a solution in the interval $(1, 2)$ .  
Also note that 
$ 
f(x) = 
\dfrac{1}{2^x} + 
\dfrac{1}{4^x} + 
\dfrac{1}{6^x} + 
\dfrac{1}{8^x} 
$ 
is decreasing; 
so the equation has a ***unique*** solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the equation as $2^{-x} + 4^{-x} + 6^{-x} + 8^{-x} = 1$. Define the function $g(x) = 2^{-x} + 4^{-x} + 6^{-x} + 8^{-x}$. Then, $g$ is a differentiable function, with $g'(x) = -2^{-x}\ln 2 - 4^{-x}\ln 4 - 6^{-x}\ln 6 - 8^{-x}\ln 8$, which is always negative. Hence, $g$ is a decreasing continuous function, so it's a one-one map. That is, there exists a single root of the above equation.

Furthermore, since $g(1) = \frac{25}{24} > 1$, and $g(2) = \frac{205}{576} < 1$, we have by the intermediate value theorem, that the root is between $1$ and $2$. Also, from the closeness of $\frac{25}{24}$ to $1$, we would be inclined to think that such a root is very close to $1$. Indeed, as far as Wolfram Alpha is concerned, the root is $1.03411$, and from our analysis, we confirm this as being the unique root.

I do not think there are purely algebraic ways of solving this problem (our method involved calculus).